# UWP how to target on 1 language without language identifier on window 10

Tags: javascript, windows, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, uwp

I am new to window 10 Universal Window Application.

I have faced on a problem on the language. I have some folders and file name consist of some language short form ("af", "it"). So they are considered to be language resources. But I don't want to rename the path since it will affect my application.

As I result, how can I ignore the checking on the resources since my application just target on 1 language.(en)

It seems weird even my names just called it/CompIt.js. (it fail completely ignored my files)

```
1>MakePRI : warning 0xdef00522: Resources found for language(s) 'af,it' but no resources found for default language(s): 
'en'. Change the default language or qualify resources with the default language. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=231899
```

I have tried to set the default languages, it doesn't work.

Tried to change the appxmanifest, but it doesn't work.

Also wanna if it is possible configure the MakePRI, I saw it is possible to create configuration file but I have no idea.

I do hope anyone can help and give me a hint.

Thanks